# AdWords - Download a campaign report with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-ads-api

I need to get a sample Python script which connects to google AdWords and downloads a campaign report. I have seen the chunk of codes but I need the complete script. what I have done so far is the following, but when I use the GetReportDownloader, I get the following error: 'AdWordsClient' object has no attribute 'GetReportDownloader'

```
 import os
import datetime
from adspygoogle.adwords.AdWordsClient import AdWordsClient
from adspygoogle.common import Utils
from pprint import pprint

google_service = 'https://adwords.google.com'
headers = {
      'email': 'me@gmail.com',
      'password': '*******',
      'userAgent': 'Arash MCC',
      'developerToken': '45345gfdg435dfgdfg',
    }


google_service = 'https://adwords.google.com'
api_version = 'v201101'

client = AdWordsClient(headers=headers)
client.use_mcc = True
client.SetDebug=True
client.SetClientCustomerId='123-456-7890'
campaign_service = client.GetCampaignService(google_service, api_version)

#report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version=api_version)
report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader('https://adwords.google.com', api_version)
```